# Adding new data in columns, from another table - SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with some records

**MASTER TABLE**

```
x------x--------------------x-------x
| Id   |      PERIOD        |   QTY |
x------x--------------------x-------x
|  1   |   2014-01-13       |   10  |
|  2   |   2014-01-06       |   30  |
x------x--------------------x-------x
```

I have another table with parameters of this record (ID)

**TABLE2**

```
x------x--------------------x------------x
| Id   |      Parameter        |   Value |
x------x--------------------x------------x
|  1   |   Humidty             |   10    |
|  1   |   Temperature         |   30    |
|  2   |   Humidty             |   50    |
|  2   |   Temperature         |   40    |
x------x--------------------x------------x
```

As result I want this: (combine based on ID)

**Result table**

```
x------x--------------------x-------------------------x
| Id   |      Period        |   Humidty | Temperature |
x------x--------------------x-------------------------x
|  1   |   2014-01-13       |   10      | 30          |
|  2   |   2014-01-06       |   50      | 40          |
x------x--------------------x-------------------------x
```

How Can I do something like that? Inner join will not work I think.

Comment: Converting rows to columns is called PIVOT. Search around for it.

Comment: Note that SQL Server is not Oracle

Comment: Please do not tag questions with multiple databases. `[oracle]` and `[sql-server]` are different platforms with different syntaxes. All you are doing is wasting the time of people who provide solutions you cannot use.

Comment: This is a question which occurs in assorted variations very commonly on this site. There are various different solutions. Which one might be best suited to your case depends upon your answer to the following question: does your real `table2` (and desired result) have a fixed number of attributes which are always present for all entries in `Master` table?

Comment: Hello, Yes It haves fixed attributes, always present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the tables and use conditional aggregation with `case` to extract the 2 columns:

```
select t1.id, t1.period,
  max(case when t2.parameter = 'Humidty' then t2.value end) Humidty,
  max(case when t2.parameter = 'Temperature' then t2.value end) Temperature
from mastertable t1 inner join table2 t2
on t2.id = t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.period
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `pivot`:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
  t_m.Id
, t_m.Period 
, t_2.Parameter
, t_2.Value
FROM @tbl_Master t_m
INNER JOIN @tbl_2 t_2 ON t_2.Id = t_m.Id
)AS t
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(t.Value)
    FOR t.Parameter IN ([Humidity], [Temperature])
)pvt
```

and sample data:

```
DECLARE @tbl_Master TABLE
(
   Id int,
   Period Date,
   QTY int

)

DECLARE @tbl_2 TABLE
(
   Id int,
   Parameter varchar(30),
   [Value] int

)

INSERT INTO @tbl_Master
(
    Id,
    Period,
    QTY
)
VALUES
  (1, '2014-01-13', 10)
, (2, '2014-01-06', 30)


INSERT INTO @tbl_2
(
    Id ,
   Parameter ,
   [Value] 
)
VALUES
  ( 1, 'Humidity', 10)
, ( 1, 'Temperature' , 30)
, ( 2, 'Humidity', 50)
, ( 2, 'Temperature' , 40)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Id    Period    Humidity       Temperature
1   2014-01-13    10            30
2   2014-01-06    50            40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Mastertable AS TABLE(Id INT,PERIOD DATE,QTY INT)
INSERT INTO @Mastertable
SELECT 1 ,'2014-01-13', 10  UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,'2014-01-06', 30

DECLARE @Childtable AS TABLE(Id INT,Parameter  VARCHAR(100), Value INT)
INSERT INTO @Childtable
SELECT  1  ,'Humidty'             ,   10  UNION ALL
SELECT  1  ,'Temperature'         ,   30  UNION ALL
SELECT  2  ,'Humidty'             ,   50  UNION ALL
SELECT  2 , 'Temperature'          ,   40  

SELECT  Id,Period,[Humidty],[Temperature]
FROM
(
SELECT  c.Id,
        m.PERIOD,
        Parameter,
        c.Value
 FROM @Mastertable m
INNER JOIN  @Childtable c
ON m.Id = c.Id
) AS srC
pivot 
(MAX(Value) FOR Parameter IN ([Humidty],[Temperature])
) AS PVT
```

Result

```
Id  Period      Humidty Temperature
----------------------------------
1   2014-01-13    10      30
2   2014-01-06    50      40
```